# Get the values of selected item from select box and display it on label and table codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I've been searching for this answer but I still got errors.
I want to display the details of product based on selected item on select box that uses select2, the items or values of select box is from the database.

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/pos_style.css') ?>">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/select2/select2.min.css') ?>">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery.js') ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js') ?>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var list = {

                    };
                list = [];
                list2 = ['maine','shar'];
                list3 = ['test', 'test'];
                list[0] = list2;
                list[1] = list3;
                console.log(list);

            $("body").on('load',function autocomplete() {
                $("#item").autocomplete(function(){
                    source: <?php echo $names ?>
                });
            });

            $("#item").on('change',function() {
                var item_name = $(this).val();
                var item_info = $("#right");

                $.ajax ({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/get/item_info",
                    data : {"prod_id":item_name},
                    datatype : 'text',
                    success : function(result) {
                        item_info.html(result);
                    } 
                });
            });

            $("#add").on('click', function() {
                var item_name = $("#item").val();
                price = $("#price").text();
                quant = $("#quantity").val();
                total = $("#amount_due").text().substr(1);
                if( $("#item").val() !== "") {
                    if (quant !== "" && !isNaN(quant) ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type : 'POST',
                            url : "<?php echo base_url()?>/get/cart",
                            data : {"price" : price, "quantity" : quant,"item_name" : item_name, "total" : total},
                            datatype : 'text',
                            success : function(result){
                                $('#tbl_head').after(result);
                                $("#quantity").val(' ');
                                $("#item").val(' ');    
                            }
                        });

                    }else {
                        alert('Quantity Is Required And Must Be Integer');
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('No Item Selected');
                }
            });

            $('#process').on('click',function () {
                var table = document.getElementById('cart');
                var x = document.getElementById('cart').rows.length;
                var y = document.getElementById('cart').rows[0].cells.length;
                var cart_items = [];
                var total = 0;              
                if (x === 1) {
                    alert('Empty!');
                }else {
                    list = [];
                    col_list = [];
                    for (row = 1; row < x; row++){
                        col_list = [];
                        total += parseInt(table.rows[row].cells[4].innerHTML.substr(1));
                        for (col = 0; col < y; col++){
                            col_list.push(table.rows[row].cells[col].innerHTML);
                        }
                        list[row-1] = col_list;

                    }
                    var obj = Object.assign({}, list);
                    cart_list = JSON.stringify(obj);
                    console.log(cart_list);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('cart',cart_list);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('total',total);
                    window.location = "<?php echo base_url() ?>/billing";
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<a href="<?php echo base_url('home') ?>"><button style="float: right; margin-top: 6px; margin-right: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Home</button></a>


<div class="main">
    <div style="padding: 0 0px;">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3 style="float: left;">Order</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="cart">
        <div id="cart-tbl">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="cart">
                <tr id="tbl_head">
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Sub Total</th>  
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="left" >
                    <form method="POST"> 

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Product Description/Name: </label>
                                                                 <select name="item_name" class="form-control"  id="item">
                                            <option value="Select Product" selected="selected">Select Product</option>

                                                    <?php foreach($item_name as $br):?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $br->prod_id?>"><?php echo $br->prod_desc?></option>
                                                            <?php endforeach;?>




                                                                                                </select>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input id="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control">
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <input style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px;" id="add" type="button" name="enter" class=" btn btn-info input-lg" value="ADD">
                    <input style="width: 100%;" id="process" type="button" name="process" class=" btn btn-success input-lg" value="PLACE ORDER">
                </div>

        </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="right">
            <label id="name">Product Name:</label><br>
            <label id="prc">Price:</label><br>
            <label id="description">Description:</label><br>
        </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php $total_amount = ""; ?>
        <h3 id="total_amount">Total Amount Due <span id="amount_due"></span> </h3>
        </div>

 </form>


       <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#item').select2({

           });
       });  </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My get.php controller

```
    public function item_info() {
        $name = "";
        $price = "";
        $prod_code = "";
        $itemName = $this->input->post('item_name');
        $this->load->model('ajax_model');
                $item_info = $this->ajax_model->item_info($itemName);
        if ($item_info) {
                    $pid= $item_info->prod_id;
            $name = $item_info->prod_desc;
            $price = $item_info->original_price;
            $prod_code = $item_info->prod_code;
            ?>
            <div class="lb">
            <label id="name">Product Name : <?php echo $name ?></label>
            </div>
<div class="lb">
                <label id="code">Prod Code: <?php echo $prod_code ?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="lb">
                <label id="prc">Price : ₱<span id="price"><?php echo $price ?></span></label>
            </div>

            <?php
        }else {
            ?>
            <div class="lb">
            <label id="name">No Item Found</label>
            </div>
            <?php
        }



    }
```

That is my pos_view.
My system is about point of sale.
This is where the user search the product
Controller

```
    public function pos(){
    $this->load->model('item_model');
    $data['names'] = $this->item_model->get_all_item();
$data['item_name'] = $this->item_model->getProduct();
    $this->load->view('pos_view',$data);
}
```

}

My model

```
    public function item_info($itemName) {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = $this->db->where('prod_id', urldecode($itemName))->get('products');
    return $sql->row();

}

public function getProduct(){
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = $this->db->get('products');
    return $sql->result();
}
```

Comment: but what does not work?

Comment: The select2 or select box doesn't work. The value of select box is the number not the product description.

Comment: It does only return the id number not the product description